# Get Cert from Azure Key Vault without using client secret

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Have an application runs on on-premise server, so can't use manage identity to authorize and fetch cert from Azure Key Vault also don't want to use Client ID and Client Secret, as its not as secured, any one get hands on Client Id and Client Secret will be able to pull cert. Any suggestions?

Comment: as far as I know, there are only three ways to securely connect in AZK. ClientId/Secret, Certicate, and Interactive (user intervention). I assume interactive is not your option, then the only option is to use certificate.

Comment: You must authenticate _somehow_ to Key Vault.